# Pass options to the scope that is internally created by preaction

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, scoping

In the reply to [this question on shadows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43618/8057), it was suggested to use the `backgrounds` library so that the shadow of one object doesn't overlap another object drawn previously.

If I understand the documentation correctly, I have to pass `on background layer` as an option to the `scope`, not to the `path`. On the other hand, a `preaction` constructs a scope internally (according to the docs).

Is it possible to change the options for the scope that is constructed internally by `preaction`? How? If not, an enhancement to TikZ would solve the "overlapping shadows" problem in an elegant way.

Comment: It's possible that the methods in the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20425/86 might help.

Comment: I should make clear that I don't *know* if that will work - I haven't tested it in this case.  But it might, and if not it might give you (or someone) a start to finding something that does work.

Comment: Are you willing to take the challenge and answer [the associated bounty question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43618/8057)? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much to my surprise, the solution from the question ["Z-level" in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20425/86) seems to work with preactions and postactions.  Here's a fairly simple example.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46957/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  /tikz/node on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@node@finish\expandafter{\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\endpgfonlayer\tikz@node@finish}%
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[ultra thick,white,preaction={on layer=back,line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,-2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[ultra thick,white,postaction={on layer=back,line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,-3) -- (4,-3);
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[ultra thick,white,preaction={line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,-2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[ultra thick,white,postaction={line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,-3) -- (4,-3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: TikZ pre- and post-actions with z-level]

The left-hand pictures have the layer set for the blue line, the right do not.  The upper have the blue line drawn as a preaction, the lower as a postaction.  In each, the vertical red line is drawn before the horizontal lines.  So for the upper two, the order of specifying is: red, blue, white.  For the lower two, the order is: red, white, blue (coincidence, I assure you).  With the "on layer" set, the order of *rendering* is: blue, red, white.  This shows that the blue line (the action line) is sent to the back by the `on layer=back` key.

Comment: Amazing! Apart from the missing `\makeatother`, could you please also provide an example for `node on layer`?

Comment: Yes, I spotted that before looking at your other question but not in time for this one!  I'll add the example for `node on layer` to the original question as it fits better there.

Comment: Aagh. `node on layer` is no longer working for me.  A workaround is `\path[on layer=back] node ...`.

Comment: Perhaps some PGF internals have changed? More than half a year has passed since you answered the other question... Is `\node[node on layer=back]` still the correct syntax?

Comment: @user946850 See original question: I've fixed the `node on layer` code.