# Is it a bug in \psellipticarc or is my calculation wrong?

Tags: pstricks

This question actually has a connection to my other question that was posted yesterday.

The following figure illustrates the problem.

[image]

Shortly speaking, the cyan dot must *always* coincide with the yellow one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,multido}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=0pt


\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+10}{37}{
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.0)(2.5,2.0)
        \psframe*[linecolor=black](-2.5,-2.0)(2.5,2.0)
        \pstVerb{/theta \i\space def}%
        \pstVerb{/a 2.25 def}%
        \pstVerb{/b 1.75 def}%
    \ifnum\i=0
        % don't draw arc!
    \else
        \psellipticarc[linecolor=cyan]{-*}(0,0)(!a b){0}{!theta}
    \fi
    \psline[linecolor=yellow]{-*}(0,0)(!theta cos a mul theta sin b mul)
    \uput{5mm}[0](0,0){\color{white}\tiny \i}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Is it a bug in `\psellipticarc` or is my calculation wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\psellipticarc[linecolor=cyan,correctAngle=false]{-*}(0,0)(!a b){0}{!theta}
```

see section `3.4. Macro \psellipticarc` in
http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-news10.pdf

Comment: `\psellipticarc[dimen=middle,linecolor=cyan,correctAngle=false]{-*}(0,0)(!a b){0}{!theta}`, the default is `dimen=outer`

Comment: Your information has been applied to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47541/9467. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I just investigated that without changing the `correctAngle` to `false` we can still solve this issue as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pstVerb
{
    /major 2.25 def
    /minor 1.75 def
    % b a t p2c ---> x y
    % where b (semi-minor), a (semi-major), t (theta)
    /p2c {dup 3 1 roll cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def
}

\psset{arrows=-*}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+10}{37}
{
    \begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.0)(2.5,2.0)
        \ifnum\i=0
            % don't draw arc!
        \else
            \psellipticarc[linecolor=cyan,dimen=middle](!major minor){0}{(!minor major \i\space p2c)}%dimen=middle must be specified!
        \fi
        \psline[linecolor=red](!minor major \i\space p2c)
        \uput{5mm}[!\i\space 10 add](0,0){\tiny$\i^\circ$}
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is in prinzipal the same