# Tikz fill only the A - B - C of three shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, clip

I am trying to draw a graph that can be represented as boolean operations on three shapes: A, B, C. The graph is `A - B - C` (or `A - (B U C)`). However, I have no Idea how to draw it using `\clip` or other commands in Tikz.

For example, here is some code adapted from [TikZ example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/), and the first picture below is what the code generates, but the second is what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(45:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
    \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \firstcircle;
      \fill[red] \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \firstcircle;
      \clip \secondcircle;
      \fill[green] \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: _]

**Edit**: To be specific, I am not trying to draw a Venn diagram, but to draw some shape from three basic shapes, but the implementation need to:

1. Allow any kind of shapes (not only circles)
2. Transparent (cannot use the white color)
3. Image border does not include B and C

See this new image as an example

[image: new image]

Comment: Well after your edit, your question is a whole other story ... Maybe remove the `venn-diagram` tag, it feels a bit misleading to me

Comment: @BambOo You are right, I should not have put the `venn-diagram` tag. Do you know any other tags I should put?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your updated question: this can be done with the [reverse clip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045) and [even odd clip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216) tricks. Assume we want to have the triangle `(-4,0) -| (0,2) -- cycle` minus the rectangle `(-1,-0.5) rectangle (1,0.5)` and minus the circle `(0.5,1) circle[radius=1cm]`. Then we need to

1. add the path of the triangle to have some non-empty picture (but we don't draw that),
2. add the rectangle with `reverse clip'` (actually there is a subtlety: the orientation of the outer path matters, which is why there is a primed version for the "other" orientation),
3. add an `even odd` `reverse clip` for the circle.

Voila.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{current reverse clip/.style={insert path={{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045
   ([xshift=-10cm,yshift=-10cm]current bounding box.south east)  -|
  ([xshift=10cm,yshift=10cm]current bounding box.north west) -| cycle
  }}},
  current reverse clip'/.style={insert path={{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045
   ([xshift=-10cm,yshift=-10cm]current bounding box.south east)  -|
  ([xshift=10cm,yshift=10cm]current bounding box.north west) -| cycle
  }}},
  even odd clip/.code={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216
  \pgfseteorule}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-4,0) -| (0,2) -- cycle;
\clip[overlay] (-1,-0.5) rectangle (1,0.5) [current reverse clip'];
\clip[overlay,even odd clip] (0.5,1) circle[radius=1cm] [current reverse clip];
\draw[left color=red,right color=blue]  (-4,0) -| (0,2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me mention that there is an experimental library `venn` which can be found [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/Venn). This hosts some variations of the above-mentioned styles. Save [this file](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/Venn/tikzlibraryvenn.code.tex) as `tikzlibraryvenn.code.tex` in some place where LaTeX can find it, such as the same directory as the file you compile. The manual can be found [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/Venn/VennManual.pdf), where you can find further clipping examples. With this library getting the diagram for the original question is as simple as

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{venn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Venn diagram={style={fill=blue},offset angle=60}]
 \Venn{-B,-C,A}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use the perhaps more intuitive syntax

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{venn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Venn diagram={style={fill=blue},offset angle=60}]
 \Venn{op={(A)/(BuC)}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

BTW, if you have grumble with the syntax, say, if you'd prefer `\Venn{op={(A)-(BuC)}}` instead, now is the time to give such feedback.

Comment: How can I present A minus B, where A is a subset of B?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 This is a simple `even odd rule` task. Depending on what you need to do maybe `\fill[even odd rule] <path B> <path A>;` is what you need, or `\clip[even odd clip] <path B> <path A>; <some other drawing commands>`.

Comment: Is there in your tool?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 These styles are in the above answer with links to the posts where they might have been invented. Some variations thereof are in the experimental library `venn`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Very nice answer !