# Will clip in Tikz to get the complement of the union?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am copying a code obtained online to clip the intersection of two closed paths and fill it with a certain color. It does not report any warning or error but I don't see the clipping working.

```
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{hobby}
  \def\A{(-1,0) circle (1.5cm);}
  \def\B{(0,0) circle (1.2cm);}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
    \fill[gray!50] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5]
      \fill[color=blue]\A;
      \fill[color=red] \B;
      \draw \A;
      \draw \B;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=1]
      \clip \B;
      \fill[color=white] \A;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

The code will highlight the intersected part in white. But if I want to high light any part outside the blue and red but in the rectangular, will the clip be able to do that?

[image]

Comment: Because you forgot a backslash in `\fill[color=white] \A;`.

Comment: My bad. Yes, it helps. I correct my post and add a different question. Would you please help.

Comment: No problem. Yes, there is `even odd clip` by LoopSpace, which can be found in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216/194703). What precisely do you want to highlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another method using the `invclip` key (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/14500):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{invclip/.style={clip,insert path={{[reset cm]
        (-16383.99999pt,-16383.99999pt) rectangle (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt)}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\A{(-1,0) circle (1.5cm)}
  \def\B{(0,0) circle (1.2cm)}

  \begin{scope}
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \clip[invclip] \B;
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \fill[fill=blue!50]\A;
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \clip[invclip] \A;
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \fill[fill=red!50]\B;
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \clip[invclip] \A \B;
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \filldraw[gray!50] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{scope}

  \draw \A;
  \draw \B;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Note the even odd rule does not clip the union of both circles.

Lines are drawn half in and half out of a region, so unless you want to reduce their width by half, draw them last.

Also, you were providing two semicolons, and everything after the first is ignored until the next `\path` etc.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{hobby}

  \begin{document}
  \def\A{(-1,0) circle (1.5cm)}
  \def\B{(0,0) circle (1.2cm)}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5]
      \fill[color=blue]\A;
      \fill[color=red] \B;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
      \clip (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2) \B \A;
      \fill[gray!50] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
    \end{scope}
    \draw \A;
    \draw \B;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

It is straightforward to determine the contour of the union with `calc` and `intersections`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
  \def\A{(-1,0) circle [radius=1.5cm];}
  \def\B{(0,0) circle [radius=1.2cm];}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5]
      \fill[color=blue]\A;
      \fill[color=red] \B;
    \end{scope}
      \draw[name path=A] \A;
      \draw[name path=B] \B;

    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=1]
     \path[name intersections={of=A and B},fill=orange]
      let \p1=($(intersection-1)-(-1,0)$),\p2=($(intersection-1)$),
       \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} in
      (intersection-1) arc[start angle=\n1,end angle=360-\n1,radius=1.5]
      arc[start angle=360-\n2,end angle=\n2+360,radius=1.2]
      -- cycle  (-3,-2) rectangle (1.7,2) ;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with Asymptote

```
size(300);
unitsize(1cm);
path c1=circle((-1,0),1.5),c2=circle(0,1.2);
picture pic;
fill(c1,blue);
fill(c2,red);
fill(pic,c1,white);
clip(pic,c2);
add(pic);
draw(c1^^c2,black+0.7bp);
shipout(bbox(2mm,Fill(.5green+.6blue)));
```

Try with PSTricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[linewidth=.7bp](-3,-2)(2,2)
{
\psset{linestyle=none}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50!blue](-3,-2)(2,2)
\pscircle[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid](-1,0){1.5cm}
\psclip{
    \pscircle[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0,0){1.2cm}}
\pscircle[fillcolor=white,fillstyle=solid](-1,0){1.5cm}
\endpsclip
}
\pscircle(-1,0){1.5cm}
\pscircle(0,0){1.2cm}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]