# What do mathematicians use to make graphs for analysis textbooks?

Tags: diagrams, graphs

Apologies if this is not the correct SE for this.

I have been transferring all of my notes to LaTeX and I have been wanting to include some custom diagrams. I often find my self having to find images to add to my notes but they are not quite what I want. I have tried using different graphic software but nothing seems to do it properly. Could anybody suggest to me any software through which I could make diagrams like this?:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend `pstricks` and some of its modules – for this kind of figures, `pst-plot`, preferably compiled with `xelatex` (pdflatex does not have the necessary tools to make the computations required by postscript).

Comment: Here there is a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298795/draw-the-dogbone-contour-for-complex-integral; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112285/contour-integrals?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I would do this in TikZ with pgfplots. I’ve never written an analysis textbook, though!

Answer (score 4):

Here is, for instance, a short code to obtain the above image:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt, x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-arrow}

\begin{document}

\psset{dimen=middle, arrowinset=0.12, unit=3cm, linejoin=1, dash=3pt 2pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(-1.4,-1.4)(1.6,1.4)
        \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-1.3,-1.32)(1.3,1.3)[$ \re z $,0][$\im z$,0]
        \psset{linecolor =SteelBlue4, linewidth = 1.2pt, ArrowInsidePos=0.3}
        \psline[ArrowInside=->](1;355)(0.2;334)\psline[ArrowInside=->](0.2;26)(1;5)
        \pscustom{\psarc{->}{1}{5}{60}\psarc(0,0){1}{60}{355}\psline(1;355)(0.2;334)%
        \psarcn{->}{0.2}{334}{135}\psarcn(0,0){0.2}{135}{26}\psline(0.2;26)(1;5)%
        \closepath}
        \psdot[dotstyle=x](-0.4,0)\uput[d](-0.4,0){$z = -1_{\varepsilon} $}
        \psline[linewidth=0.4pt, linestyle=dashed]{<->}(1;110)(0,0)(0.2;-130)
        \uput{2pt}[ur](1;55){$C_R$}\uput{1pt}[ul](0.2;135){$C_\varepsilon$}
        \uput{2pt}[ur](0.7;110){$R$}\uput{2pt}[ul](0.5,0.1){$I^{+} $}\uput{2pt}[d](0.75,-0.1){$I^{-} $}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question “What do mathematicians use to make graphs for analysis textbooks?” but that is not answerable in a meaningful manner anyway,

Comment: @HenriMenke: I only had mentioned pstricks in a comment first, then decided it was worth giving an example.