# LaTeX "under construction", "in work" or "work in progress" symbols

Tags: symbols, packages

Are there "*under construction*", "*in work*" or "*work in progress*" symbols in one of the LaTeX symbol packages?

Something like [this (google search link)](https://www.google.com/search?q=under%20construction%20symbol&tbm=isch).

I have tried [detexity](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but could not find an appropriate symbol.

The following example shows what I am actually trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[right=10cm,paperheight=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[textwidth=8cm,shadow]{todonotes}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

  \section*{Tasks}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Design \cmark
    \item Implementation \todo[fancyline]{insert "under construction" symbol here}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

Comment: Why do you not insert such a graphics directly? I am not sure that such a symbol exists in some font

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If I don't find anything suitable, I am going to use `\includegraphics`. However, I thought maybe someone has stumbled upon such a symbol in one of the packages.

Comment: @sergej Maybe lookup The Noun Project. They have a pretty good svg icons that you can convert to pdf and include it directly in your document. A couple of examples: http://thenounproject.com/search/?q=construction
 http://thenounproject.com/term/work-in-progress/42732/

Comment: @szantaii Thanks, this looks exactly like what I was looking for. Maybe you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well it's not rocket science either

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[limb/.style={line cap=round,line width=1.5mm,line join=bevel}]
\draw[line width=2mm,rounded corners,fill=yellow] (-2,0) -- (0,-2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\fill (1.5mm,7mm) circle (1.5mm);
\fill(0,-7.5mm) -- ++(10mm,0mm) -- ++(120:2mm)--++(100:1mm)--++(150:2mm) arc (70:170:2.5mm and 1mm);
\draw[limb] (-7.5mm,-6.5mm)--++(70:4mm)--++(85:4mm) coordinate(a)--++(-45:5mm)--(-2.5mm,-6.5mm);
\fill[rotate around={45:(a)}] ([shift={(-0.5mm,0.55mm)}]a) --++(0mm,-3mm)--++
        (7mm,-0.5mm)coordinate(b)--++(0mm,4mm)coordinate(c)--cycle;
\draw[limb] ([shift={(-0.6mm,-0.4mm)}]b) --++(-120:5mm) ([shift={(-0.5mm,-0.5mm)}]c) --++
        (-3mm,0mm)--++(-100:3mm)coordinate (d);
\draw[ultra thick] (d) -- ++(-45:1.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: I really, really like this.

Comment: with the new `pic` feature of tikz this can be packaged in a nice object that can be placed/customised arbitrarily. Is there any effort to collect and package in an archive all these symbols in `pic` objects (like a clipart archive for vector graphics)?

Comment: @Bordaigorl Not that I'm aware of but you can put it next to the [superheros](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47388/using-tikz-how-to-draw-an-elliptical-arc-starting-from-point-a-to-point-b-with?lq=1#comment97553_47394) library. 1010011010 Thanks for the thumbs up.

Answer (score 25):

I didn't find such a sign in the LaTeX symbol guide, so here is a `tikz` solution: Look for a nice sign on Wikipedia, download the `svg` file, convert `svg` to `tikz` with [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org). Then you can build a command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{cec1d24}{RGB}{236,29,36}
\definecolor{cffffff}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\ucmark}{\tikz[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-0.02,xscale=0.02, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]%
  {\path[fill=cec1d24,nonzero rule] (635.8833,600.0000) .. controls
    (651.0771,599.6647) and (665.7558,591.6224) .. (673.9783,577.5525) .. controls
    (682.1001,563.3625) and (681.7384,546.6500) .. (674.5074,533.1862) --
    (378.4699,21.6487) .. controls (370.6590,8.7662) and (356.3424,0.0975) ..
    (340.1099,-0.0063) .. controls (323.6499,0.0972) and (309.3362,8.7657) ..
    (301.4862,21.6487) -- (5.4612,533.1862) .. controls (-1.7257,546.6500) and
    (-2.0877,563.3625) .. (5.9903,577.5525) .. controls (14.2570,591.6225) and
    (28.9353,599.6650) .. (44.0853,600.0000) -- (635.8853,600.0000);
    \path[fill=cffffff,nonzero rule] (340.1208,75.7875) -- (71.0683,540.8450) --
    (608.8933,540.8450) -- (340.1058,75.7950);
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (303.5900,225.7800) .. controls
    (280.4500,225.7300) and (276.9200,248.1400) .. (276.8800,250.6200) .. controls
    (276.9200,262.4400) and (285.4000,277.1700) .. (309.1600,279.4100) .. controls
    (309.1600,279.4100) and (313.7700,280.0900) .. (313.6600,283.0900) .. controls
    (313.7700,285.9400) and (313.7800,284.9700) .. (312.3400,286.5300) .. controls
    (310.8500,288.2300) and (298.5500,299.6400) .. (298.3100,302.6600) .. controls
    (296.9800,316.8800) and (300.1800,335.2800) .. (303.0900,345.9400) .. controls
    (303.0900,345.9400) and (306.6000,354.7800) .. (303.8800,361.0000) .. controls
    (301.0600,367.4700) and (289.0000,397.7400) .. (288.0000,399.5600) .. controls
    (285.1300,404.8200) and (284.0000,409.1400) .. (285.8800,415.4100) .. controls
    (284.6600,416.1100) and (264.4700,428.8800) .. (264.4700,428.8800) .. controls
    (264.4700,428.8800) and (261.3500,421.5100) .. (253.5900,419.3800) .. controls
    (245.7000,417.1100) and (239.1800,418.1800) .. (232.7200,405.9100) --
    (226.8800,396.4100) .. controls (226.8800,396.4100) and (225.6700,392.9300) ..
    (219.7500,391.6200) .. controls (213.9300,390.4900) and (206.1000,388.3000) ..
    (202.8100,388.4700) .. controls (198.6100,388.8800) and (195.2200,387.7300) ..
    (189.5900,394.2800) .. controls (185.0800,399.5300) and (112.8800,524.4700) ..
    (112.8800,524.4700) -- (286.4100,524.4700) .. controls (286.4100,524.4700) and
    (290.7100,524.0000) .. (289.5900,519.9700) .. controls (288.2700,516.1900) and
    (267.3800,441.8100) .. (267.3800,441.8100) -- (291.4400,426.7500) .. controls
    (291.4400,426.7500) and (293.3600,429.9900) .. (300.4400,426.7500) .. controls
    (307.3800,423.4800) and (309.9700,421.7500) .. (309.9700,421.7500) .. controls
    (309.9700,421.7500) and (313.9200,421.4900) .. (313.4100,413.0300) .. controls
    (316.1700,411.3100) and (341.9700,395.0600) .. (341.9700,395.0600) .. controls
    (341.9700,395.0600) and (332.8400,417.6000) .. (331.9100,427.5600) .. controls
    (331.2100,437.4600) and (327.6900,504.1200) .. (327.6900,504.1200) .. controls
    (327.6900,504.1200) and (328.1300,509.2200) .. (324.7800,510.2200) .. controls
    (321.2800,511.1700) and (305.7200,515.5000) .. (305.7200,515.5000) .. controls
    (305.7200,515.5000) and (301.3900,516.2100) .. (301.5000,519.7200) .. controls
    (301.3900,523.0400) and (303.0200,524.3400) .. (304.9400,524.4700) .. controls
    (306.9300,524.3400) and (355.7200,524.4700) .. (355.7200,524.4700) .. controls
    (355.7200,524.4700) and (360.7100,525.0000) .. (361.5300,518.4100) .. controls
    (362.3400,511.9900) and (371.5900,445.5000) .. (371.5900,445.5000) .. controls
    (371.5900,445.5000) and (367.5700,444.4500) .. (367.6200,440.5000) .. controls
    (367.5700,436.3200) and (367.5600,433.2000) .. (368.9400,431.5000) .. controls
    (370.1600,429.9500) and (384.8300,413.0400) .. (394.8800,389.5300) .. controls
    (396.4200,386.0300) and (397.5600,389.1300) .. (397.7800,390.0600) .. controls
    (398.2100,390.7500) and (417.2800,442.6600) .. (419.4700,444.7200) .. controls
    (421.8400,446.5600) and (473.3600,488.2300) .. (474.5000,489.0900) .. controls
    (475.6400,489.8600) and (478.9100,492.1100) .. (479.0000,499.3800) .. controls
    (478.9100,506.7600) and (475.9700,512.6300) .. (473.9700,514.9700) .. controls
    (472.0500,517.1900) and (468.8000,520.4500) .. (468.6900,521.8400) .. controls
    (468.8000,523.3800) and (470.2800,524.3400) .. (471.3400,524.4700) .. controls
    (472.5600,524.3400) and (479.2500,524.3400) .. (479.8100,524.4700) .. controls
    (480.5500,524.3400) and (489.3400,525.0100) .. (495.4100,514.1900) .. controls
    (501.7300,503.5300) and (513.1200,484.3400) .. (513.1200,484.3400) .. controls
    (513.1200,484.3400) and (515.5800,480.5600) .. (512.0600,478.2500) .. controls
    (508.4000,476.0100) and (502.7100,474.7100) .. (499.3800,471.1200) .. controls
    (495.8600,467.5500) and (462.9400,429.6400) .. (462.3400,428.8800) .. controls
    (461.9600,428.3400) and (457.7100,423.7600) .. (452.2800,426.2200) .. controls
    (450.7000,424.0900) and (448.8400,421.2200) .. (448.8400,421.2200) .. controls
    (448.8400,421.2200) and (439.4600,364.4600) .. (429.5300,340.4100) .. controls
    (431.8000,339.0000) and (434.8100,336.7200) .. (434.8100,336.7200) .. controls
    (434.8100,336.7200) and (442.7200,343.5500) .. (449.3800,336.4400) .. controls
    (456.0900,329.2300) and (455.6000,329.4100) .. (454.4100,326.1600) .. controls
    (453.3200,322.9000) and (452.8300,321.9100) .. (450.4400,320.5900) .. controls
    (448.2700,319.3000) and (444.5200,315.5500) .. (444.6200,308.9700) .. controls
    (444.5200,302.5400) and (441.7400,284.8000) .. (438.5300,277.2800) .. controls
    (435.5500,269.8300) and (434.5600,261.5500) .. (422.9100,256.4400) .. controls
    (404.4800,248.2100) and (379.8000,243.3100) .. (361.8100,247.9700) .. controls
    (356.8300,249.3000) and (340.8200,261.0500) .. (339.3100,261.9700) .. controls
    (337.8900,262.6800) and (331.6400,265.2600) .. (332.1900,259.8400) .. controls
    (333.4500,247.4700) and (322.7500,225.7300) .. (303.5900,225.7800) --
    cycle(394.8800,275.9700) .. controls (394.8800,275.9700) and
    (408.4700,275.8400) .. (411.5300,276.2200) .. controls (414.3400,276.5000) and
    (416.0300,280.1900) .. (416.0300,280.1900) -- (429.0000,325.8800) --
    (424.2500,328.7800) .. controls (421.5800,323.2700) and (397.9000,287.2600) ..
    (393.0300,280.4700) .. controls (389.9100,276.1000) and (394.8800,275.9700) ..
    (394.8800,275.9700) -- cycle(331.0000,332.8100) .. controls
    (331.5700,332.7900) and (332.2200,332.9700) .. (332.7200,333.2800) .. controls
    (337.8300,336.2000) and (347.5100,344.5400) .. (355.7200,356.0000) .. controls
    (356.7000,357.3200) and (355.7200,361.2800) .. (355.7200,361.2800) --
    (348.5900,376.0600) .. controls (348.5900,376.0600) and (317.8500,395.3700) ..
    (315.5000,396.9100) .. controls (312.9600,398.3000) and (311.5500,396.9300) ..
    (313.9400,393.7500) .. controls (327.6400,375.1200) and (332.7200,353.0000) ..
    (329.5300,335.1200) .. controls (329.2600,333.4800) and (330.0500,332.8500) ..
    (331.0000,332.8100) -- cycle;}}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\section*{Tasks}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Design \cmark
\item Implementation \ucmark
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Teach 'em how to fish, nice!

Comment: About "convert svg to tikz with Inkscape. ", "$ man inkscape | grep tikz" returns nothing, so I guess there is an implicit intermediary step there. Would you mind making it explicit?

Comment: @Erwann There is a (now unmaintained) python program [`svg2tikz`](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) which can be used directly or from Inkscape as a plugin. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370876)

Answer (score 13):

If you're open to using XeTeX or LuaTeX, you might find some possibilities in the excellent [`fontawesome` font](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and its [corresponding package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome) (containing easy-to-use macros). Here are a few options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome} % requires XeTeX or LuaTeX
\newcommand{\cmark}{\faOk}
\newcommand{\pmark}{\faWarningSign}

\begin{document}
  \section*{Tasks}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Design \cmark
    \item Implementation \pmark 
    \item Another option \faWrench 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Agreeing with Christian Hupfer, you can only include the graphics directly. There is no symbol explicitly for this. Possibly, you can reconstruct using `TikZ` or other packages. For now, this should do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[right=10cm,paperheight=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[textwidth=8cm,shadow]{todonotes}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

  \section*{Tasks}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Design \cmark
    \item Implementation \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{1.jpg}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `1.jpg`, is the name of the picture(you can use any one you preferand rename accordingly). The `scale`, is what I suggest you to meddle with. Try different values to suit your needs.

You can also use the lower level commands `\kern` to ensure it is perfect.

Comment: `height=1ex` is probably in the right direction. Maybe `1.5ex`. Then it is the same height as the font.

Answer (score 2):

The bclogo package has a `\bcpanchant`-macro that creates a [image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bclogo}%  \bcpanchant
\newcommand{\underconstruction}{\marginpar{\bcpanchant}}

\begin{document}
\bcpanchant
\underconstruction
\end{document}
```

Worked also with pdflatex.