# Converting an SVG image to TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I am to convert an SVG image to TikZ code. I have never done that before thus I have a few questions.
First of all do I need Inkscape or any other program like this? Maybe there is a method using just Python?
Have you ever done that before? Are there any typical errors or problems?

Comment: Inkscape 0.48 offers export to LaTeX as `pstricks` code. It works okay-ish. If you want to use it in `tikz`, you have to fiddle a little bit. (I'm using it as an export path for maps; make all lines between points non-curved, export, remove the `pstricks` `line to` clutter, plot using `\draw plot file{}`. pgf manual section 22.4 helps a bit, but not much: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Thanks! So that means that the only thing that I need is Inkscape 0.48? I think that pstricks will be good too.

Comment: The newest Inkscape will do, I just know that the functionality is implemented from v0.48 onwards.

Comment: @Huang_d Inkscape can export Ti*k*Z code.

Comment: You might need a plugin. There is also a command line programme `svg2tikz`, at least for Unix-ish systems.

Comment: I voted to reopen this because the linked question turned out to concern conversion of a bitmap image. This means that, for example, an answer I was thinking of adding which *would* address *this* question, would *not* address *that* one ....

Answer (score 16):

Although [How to export svg to tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/how-to-export-svg-to-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1) turned out to involve conversion of a bitmap image, rather than an SVG, parts of the answers there address the question here. In particular, the second stages of those answers, which involve conversion of the traced SVG to Ti*k*Z are relevant. That is, you can use Inkscape with the Ti*k*Z extension to export `.tikz` code. The code will not be very good and will be of little use for further editing, but it will work. It will also not be very efficient, but that is not always a pressing concern.

However, installing Inkscape just for this may be overkill. If you already have SVG - that is, your situation is not like that of the OP in [How to export svg to tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/how-to-export-svg-to-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1), who is starting with a PNG rather than an SVG - then you might prefer other options.

`svg2tikz` is a command line programme for Unix-ish systems which can convert SVG images to Ti*k*Z code, as the the name suggests.

The project is hosted at https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz and based on Python.

If Inkscape *is* installed, `svg2tikz` can cooperate with it by using some Inkscape extensions. However, Inkscape is an optional dependency and not a requirement for basic functionality.