# Is it possible to convert vector graphics files into tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, conversion, svg, inkscape

I've not really used tikz much (to say the least); and I'm used to working on my diagrams in LibreOffice Draw and Inkscape, saving them as `.osd` or `.svg` files.

Is there a way I could convert those formats into (human-readable) tikz instructions which I could inline in my LaTeX code and maybe continue tweaking there?

Comment: Can't you save you diagrams as `.pdf`?

Comment: You can export Ti*k*Z code from Inkscape. (Probably you have to install the plugin - I forget the details.) I'm not sure you'd call the result human-readable. It is not a good basis for tweaking, for sure. But if you don't know Ti*k*Z, why not tweak before export or export PDF, as @Bernard suggests?

Comment: @Bernard: I can, but how would that help me?

Comment: @cfr: I'm sure once I get something human-readable in TikZ (if I can get something like that) I'll be able to tweak it without learning TikZ before. Plus, maybe I've learned TikZ and I just want to convert my old graphics.

Comment: You can insert your diagrams with `\includegraphics{some_diagram}` .

Comment: Well, you were the one who said you hadn't used it much at all. If you have, you have. The output is generally human-readable in some sense, but it is not really human-editable, in most cases. That is, it is much more difficult to edit than human-written code. It is also usually very, very, very verbose.

Comment: Have you seen e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370876?