# How to build a totally new Figure in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

[Here](https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/isecure-draft/tmkjrydcqbfx) you can find an Overleaf template in which it is included a figure called "IseCure.pdf". In that figure there is a symbol like a letter "i" inscribed in a circle. And that symbol can't be selected when the figure is opened in Adobe Acrobat.

My question is: is it possible to build such a symbol, in a more or less simple way, with TikZ?
Or, more in general, is it possible to "bring" to TikZ any figure (for example, something in jpeg format)?

Thank you so much.

Comment: With Ti*k*Z, it's quite simple. You could use a soft to produce a SVG file and import it in Ti*k*Z, or create it with a bit of work and Bezier curves.

Comment: Thanks, but, how can I import a SVG file in TikZ? Can you recommend me any manual or tutorial?

Comment: [There's a thread here about that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370973/204164).

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try.Thanks from a naive village boy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decent mockup with TikZ. Just a few lines and arcs and an ellipse. Obviously the font in ISeCure is wrong, but you get the idea.

[image]

The macro `\circi` will produce the symbol with radius 1cm. Use `\scalebox` to adjust the size in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\circi}{\tikz[baseline=-1cm, black!60]{
    \fill(-.4,-.08){[rounded corners] to[bend left=5] (-.1,.2) --++ (250:1.15)} 
        -- (-110:1) arc (-110:180:1) arc (180:360:.04) arc (180:-85:1-.08) to[out=185, in=250] (-.1,-.75)
        {[rounded corners] --++ (70:1.05) -- (90:.35) --++ (-.3,-.2)}
        {[rounded corners=1] -- (-.45,-.03)--cycle};
    \fill[rotate=-20](90:.62) ellipse (.18 and .2);}}

\begin{document}

\textsf{\textbf{ISeCure}}\hspace{-.3em}\scalebox{.22}{\circi}

\circi

\end{document}
```

For reference, here is the image outlined with `\draw` instead of `\fill`:

[image]