# Regional map of Namibia on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, mapping, getmap

For a research project, I need a regionally disaggregated map of Namibia, similar to [this](https://gitlab.com/conradolandia/WorldMap-Tikz/-/tree/master) world map, only for the regions of Namibia. Using TikZ, I would then define values for each region based on a certain variable. Now I can't find a template for this anywhere, so would anyone have an idea where to look or advise me on how to go about creating one from scratch on LaTeX/Overleaf? Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using [this svg map of Namibia from Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Namibia_14_regions-numbered.svg), combined with [`svg2tikz` tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370876/16595) would be an idea. (SVG is a vector format like PDF/PGF/TikZ and the regions simply look like closed polygons.)

Comment: Viewing World.tex you see that each country is a closed path of its outer boundary (not sure, which coordinate system they use). For the regions or counties you'd need to know their coordinates and create several (probably closed) pathes yourself. First approach would be to have only few points, e.g. just a course region. // Then call like shown in map.tex .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file [`Namibia 14 regions-numbered.svg`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Namibia_14_regions-numbered.svg)<sup>[CC-BY-SA-4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en)</sup> by Wikimedia user [Barada-nikto](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Barada-nikto) already contains the regions in a vector format.

Since I can't get [`svg2tikz`](https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz) to run, I'm going to use the [`svg.path` library](https://tikz.dev/library-svg-path) which allows us to insert the raw SVG path specification which I will copy from the raw svg file.

Since those are a lot of coordinates, I can't post all of them here. I'll leave them out but you can find them in the `path` tag under the `d` paramater.

The file also contains the borders between the neighbouring states and the full coastline. However, these are specified somewhat different (mixing absolute and relative coordinates) which makes it harder to transform them inside PGF/TikZ – it seems the `svg.path` can't deal with all combinations of path specifications and transformations.

You can alter the appearence of the regions with the styles

- `/tikz/Namibia/every region` for all regions and
- `/tikz/Namibia/<region name>` for each individual region.

---

If we'll add all we'll get this picture:

[image]

Now, if we we use

```
\path[Namibia/every region/.try, Namibia/\region/.try,
  fill=red!\col!blue,
  path picture={\foreach \j in {0,45,...,359}
    \path ([shift=(\j:10mm)]path picture bounding box.center)
      node[white] {\i};}
];
```

inside the `\foreach \region` loop we'll get

[image]

The `path picture` is only used to show the order of the regions that follow the source map's order.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\tikzset{
  Namibia/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/Namibia}{#1},
  insert svg/.style={insert path={\pgfextra\pgfpathsvg{#1}\endpgfextra}},
  Namibia={
    Karas/.style       ={},% ǁKaras
    Hardap/.style      ={insert svg={m 994.21233,959.21099 3.22503,0.43108 30.04674,0.10644 0.053,45.31299 v 0.5913 43.5921 l -2.15,0.2686 -0.645,-0.5374 -0.9676,0.107 -0.6989,0.1618 -5.2674,2.473 -0.9676,0.3225 -0.5923,-0.053 -2.0414,-0.9153 -4.5151,-0.8612 -0.7525,-0.2139 -0.6988,-0.3235 -1.1299,-0.8608 -1.1824,-0.4293 -2.6328,-0.3768 h -2.2575 l -1.23635,0.215 -0.37616,0.2144 -1.45132,1.0751 -0.59127,0.3231 -0.37627,-0.1607 -0.43001,-0.4838 -4.19258,-6.1815 -0.26877,-0.2687 -0.43106,-0.2688 -0.43002,0.2151 -0.37617,0.3224 -1.02023,0.9671 -4.24633,2.2043 -0.75198,0.2145 -20.58818,-1.7723 -3.60023,-1.7737 -1.07501,-0.8606 -3.17132,-1.6662 -10.58891,0.9132 -22.79037,5.3208 -6.23509,0.5375 -9.03015,-0.9127 -0.64501,-0.215 -0.48377,-0.2688 -0.3225,-0.054 -0.32251,0.1607 -0.86108,0.4311 -1.34376,0.5375 -1.07503,0.6983 -0.16125,8.8689 -7.79387,-3.2788 -0.75143,-0.1069 -2.47309,0.9137 h -1.45127 l -3.49381,1.0208 -0.91322,0.1074 -0.26876,-0.2687 -0.16232,-0.5913 -0.0538,-0.6445 -0.16125,-0.5912 -0.48377,-0.4837 -1.28894,-0.8063 -2.15004,-0.6994 -1.98879,-0.2687 -1.18251,-0.8062 -0.80626,-0.3758 -0.37627,-0.2687 -8.33137,-1.6126 -0.80625,0.053 h -0.59127 l -0.37625,-0.2146 -0.37627,-0.5373 -1.18252,-2.0963 -0.37626,-0.4823 -0.42999,-0.1079 -0.53751,0.8599 -1.77379,3.817 -0.7525,1.075 -1.98879,1.3954 -0.75251,-2.4188 v -0.4838 l 0.215,-0.3225 0.21393,-0.3768 -0.0538,-0.2144 -0.32359,-0.3758 -0.43,-0.323 -0.53751,-0.3226 -0.53751,-0.2149 -0.59126,0.054 -2.36504,0.6993 -0.48269,0.2139 -0.43108,0.2689 -0.0538,0.4832 0.0538,0.4837 2.47363,12.6852 -0.26876,0.3231 -0.75251,0.054 -2.09523,-0.6998 -1.1825,-0.055 -0.91377,0.107 -0.64501,0.323 -0.59126,0.2688 h -0.64501 l -0.59126,-0.4827 -9.56874,-12.7395 -0.48267,-0.5376 -0.48376,-0.3226 h -0.64501 l -0.59126,0.1072 -1.77378,0.5373 -0.53751,0.1076 h -0.43 l -0.215,-0.4306 -0.16126,-0.4832 -3.76256,-25.1554 -1.12984,-4.1388 -43.75213,-0.323 h -0.10751 l -0.96751,-1.9351 -0.645,-2.0436 -0.10751,-4.085 -0.59126,-1.935 -2.68754,-5.1064 -1.12985,-1.5587 -2.36394,-2.25542 -0.64503,-1.50558 -1.61251,-1.88123 -0.26877,-1.28953 0.16127,-0.53752 0.645,-0.75138 0.16125,-0.26877 v -2.09634 l -0.21393,-0.96806 -1.07501,-1.93499 -1.02127,-2.58111 -2.5263,-4.89134 -1.02019,-3.54755 -0.91376,-1.66682 -0.32359,-2.3645 -0.3225,-0.75252 0.215,-1.02127 v -1.71949 l -0.21607,-1.72002 -0.37625,-1.12983 0.37625,-0.69876 0.26875,-1.39753 0.37626,-0.6993 0.26875,-0.16071 0.43002,-0.0554 0.37625,-0.16071 0.21393,-0.48376 0.645,-1.23681 -0.37625,-0.64448 0.0548,-2.84933 -0.8611,-2.47253 -0.10642,-0.86056 0.64394,-7.36279 -0.26876,-1.82754 -0.53752,-1.39752 26.55294,2.57951 1.18251,1.77433 0.37625,0.37572 0.16126,0.16178 0.21393,0.16072 0.37626,0.10804 0.53751,0.10696 1.07502,0.10804 3.44005,-0.32411 4.73006,0.80625 1.02128,-0.10696 0.64394,0.0543 5.42992,1.45181 13.70647,6.12599 -0.37626,3.97756 0.215,1.28948 0.53751,1.39806 2.84879,1.45181 1.34378,0.10643 3.4938,-0.16179 0.43001,-0.16072 0.26875,-0.26875 0.215,-0.43054 0.21394,-0.48376 0.37625,-0.42948 0.59126,-0.32304 2.20486,-0.0548 6.07385,-1.88128 0.32251,-0.0538 1.45126,0.1618 h 0.53751 l 0.53751,-0.21501 2.90254,-1.55826 0.32251,-0.10695 -0.1075,0.37572 -0.4816,0.97235 -0.21502,0.59127 -0.10696,0.69984 0.16179,0.96697 -0.16179,0.37679 -0.37571,0.26876 -0.91377,0.10642 -0.215,0.0543 -0.32251,0.21446 -0.0548,0.53751 0.26877,0.80626 2.63378,1.98823 2.63327,0.53751 -0.48322,-1.23573 -0.86055,-3.11809 0.5375,-1.34376 1.77432,-1.77325 0.43001,-0.26875 0.37625,-0.0554 1.50503,0.43053 4.24576,0.26877 h 0.43055 l 0.21394,-0.16179 0.215,-0.32251 0.26875,-0.5918 0.1075,-0.37518 -0.0548,-0.32412 -0.37571,-1.12877 -0.16179,-0.37571 -0.32252,-0.215 -0.43,-0.16179 -3.60131,-1.01965 h -0.43 l -0.80626,0.42946 -0.43054,0.0538 -4.08562,-0.96697 -0.3225,-0.21501 -0.0548,-0.3225 0.0548,-0.48375 0.75144,-2.90203 2.25754,-4.6231 0.32303,-0.37518 0.26877,-0.21501 0.64447,0.42947 0.43053,0.48377 0.10697,0.26875 0.16179,2.52684 0.10697,0.37516 0.37625,0.16233 h 3.11756 l 0.5375,-0.10803 0.43053,-0.32305 4.89187,-4.78329 0.16127,-0.42946 v -0.48376 l -0.37626,-1.61253 -0.16126,-0.43054 -0.26875,-0.26876 -3.22507,-1.77325 -0.21446,-0.16232 -0.21446,-0.21446 0.1075,-0.37572 0.16126,-0.43055 5.42883,-10.75017 0.6993,-0.96751 0.53752,-0.0548 1.1293,0.53751 0.86002,0.75251 0.96804,0.3225 0.91324,0.0548 1.07501,-0.21446 1.77431,-0.0543 2.09575,0.53752 3.81686,-0.91377 2.36448,-1.02127 2.79506,-2.09466 3.17075,-0.59287 h 1.93558 l 2.09575,0.69929 0.80625,0.37571 0.43056,0.6993 0.21392,1.34378 0.0548,2.20432 0.75145,1.12876 1.66734,0.32358 4.24525,-0.69929 3.17129,-0.10696 2.68755,-0.64502 0.75251,-0.0543 0.16126,0.0543 -1.72003,1.66628 -0.32251,0.43055 -0.10748,0.43108 v 0.48214 l 0.21392,2.6338 -0.0538,0.3768 -0.26875,0.21338 -1.72004,0.53751 -0.16125,0.32412 v 0.48215 l 0.59127,3.06433 0.16232,0.215 0.26876,0.16071 0.75143,0.21447 0.37626,0.16233 0.16125,0.21339 0.10751,0.43055 0.37625,4.51506 0.26875,-0.215 7.90138,0.10697 0.53751,-0.0538 0.37518,-0.10696 0.16233,-0.48375 0.37518,-0.48323 0.70145,-0.37626 8.97532,-0.26873 2.41878,0.69822 0.43109,0.21499 0.37517,0.3225 1.72003,2.15005 0.37626,0.26876 0.43001,0.10803 1.88129,-0.86001 0.43,-0.10805 0.43108,0.32251 0.75144,0.21501 0.75251,-0.10696 0.86001,-0.21501 3.65506,-1.61253 2.04359,-0.48323 0.53752,-0.32304 0.10644,-0.53751 0.10749,-1.07501 0.1075,-0.43055 0.43002,-0.37572 4.08613,-1.88128 3.22505,-1.88128 1.07503,-0.0538 1.34377,2.09628 -0.0548,0.64394 4.35651,8.54692 0.26875,0.215 0.3225,-0.215 0.75251,-0.80625 0.48269,-0.37681 0.43,-0.16071 0.59235,0.32251 0.48269,0.43108 2.31235,2.47253 0.75143,0.42948 0.96751,0.32412 3.81739,0.69822 0.64502,-0.0543 8.81406,-3.49381 0.43,-0.10642 2.52629,0.16071 0.32359,0.15964 v 0.26876 l -0.21501,0.42947 -0.0538,0.43054 0.16124,0.37573 0.91377,0.16178 4.40647,0.16233 0.21503,-0.10805 0.21501,-0.21499 2.15009,-2.68755 0.59118,-0.3225 0.69877,-0.0538 1.12986,0.26876 0.43001,0.37517 0.21396,0.53752 0.21606,9.03066 0,0 z}},
    Khomas/.style      ={},
    Kunene/.style      ={},
    Erongo/.style      ={},
    Otjozondjupa/.style={},
    Omusati/.style     ={insert svg={m 755.28973,631.11574 0.16233,-0.48375 0.0538,-1.12878 h 16.01776 l 47.24648,0.0538 0.0543,3.38631 1.39751,3.06379 1.18253,1.66628 0.48376,0.96752 0.64501,1.55878 0.37517,4.19256 -16.98526,17.57653 -0.0538,0.80626 0.86001,0.43001 5.42883,3.22506 2.04362,0.80625 1.71894,1.18252 0.59234,2.47254 0.0538,2.63379 2.36503,18.97406 -0.91377,2.8488 -1.50502,2.31128 0.26876,2.8488 2.09521,5.48259 -0.32251,2.95628 -1.93503,1.88129 0.80625,1.61252 1.12878,1.39753 1.23626,0.42999 1.02127,0.69878 -1.55877,0.80625 -1.82754,0.21502 -1.9361,0.96752 -1.82645,1.23626 -1.66735,0.59127 -1.77379,0.37625 -1.45127,0.53751 -1.45127,0.37625 v 0.64502 0.75251 l -4.99882,1.61252 -2.84881,-0.21501 -2.90254,-0.64499 -10.91142,1.50501 -13.00771,0.1075 -2.20378,0.43 -0.10751,2.04254 0.215,2.20378 2.63272,-0.16126 -0.0538,2.7413 -0.86109,1.93504 -5.96634,-0.16125 0.43001,-2.15004 0.59231,-0.69877 0.53752,-0.86001 -0.21499,-2.25753 -1.07504,-1.72003 -1.34376,-1.12876 -0.91376,-1.39753 -1.9877,-5.9126 0.32249,-5.26758 0.86002,-5.21383 -0.86002,-2.84879 -1.29001,-2.79506 -1.88128,-6.12759 -0.26876,-3.4938 0.43108,-7.20263 -0.80626,-19.0278 -1.34377,-6.2351 -4.56883,-9.6214 -0.64501,-2.4188 0.91377,-1.02126 0.43,-0.80626 0.16126,-0.96751 0.16125,-1.34378 -0.26875,-1.12876 -1.93503,-1.23628 -0.16126,-1.34376 0.96752,-1.18252 1.50503,-2.3113 0.37625,-1.07501 0.91375,-1.77379 0.26877,-0.86 -0.32252,-0.3225 0,0 z}},
    Oshana/.style      ={insert svg={m 805.8693,662.77499 0.0538,-0.80626 16.98526,-17.57653 v 0.26875 l 0.86109,2.7413 7.14887,-0.96752 8.60014,-1.23626 v 16.66276 l 0.64502,0.1075 0.645,0.75252 0.26877,1.07501 0.26874,4.08507 -0.37625,3.01004 -0.53752,1.34377 -2.15003,3.06381 -0.80627,0.53749 -0.59233,0.86002 0.0548,2.31129 0.48267,2.25755 -0.26874,3.7088 0.37625,1.29002 0.64501,1.18252 0.75251,2.6338 2.09522,2.58004 0.215,1.34377 -0.91377,0.7525 h -1.02128 l -1.02018,0.43001 -1.45126,1.88128 -2.0963,2.15003 -1.77376,2.4188 -0.64503,1.61251 -0.26874,1.6663 0.0548,3.11754 0.32251,0.69876 0.1075,1.34376 1.55878,3.49381 0.86001,1.55878 0.48375,1.34378 0.80628,1.02127 1.55769,1.02125 -0.37626,1.55878 -0.9675,0.48376 -0.75251,0.59125 0.0538,1.39753 0.59125,3.65506 0.43109,1.18251 -0.0548,1.18252 -3.7088,-2.09629 -1.66735,-0.37625 -1.77378,0.10751 -3.97757,-0.48377 -5.96634,-1.55877 -1.93557,-0.215 -1.66681,0.215 -8.81299,0.1075 0.10641,-2.79503 v -0.75251 -0.64502 l 1.45128,-0.37625 1.45127,-0.53751 1.77379,-0.37625 1.66735,-0.59127 1.82645,-1.23626 1.93611,-0.96752 1.82644,-0.21502 1.55878,-0.80625 -1.02126,-0.69878 -1.23627,-0.42999 -1.12769,-1.39753 -0.80626,-1.61252 1.93503,-1.88129 0.32251,-2.95628 -2.09521,-5.48259 -0.26876,-2.8488 1.50502,-2.31128 0.91377,-2.8488 -2.36503,-18.97406 -0.0538,-2.63379 -0.59234,-2.47254 -1.72002,-1.18252 -2.04362,-0.80625 -5.42883,-3.22506 -0.85894,-0.43001 0,0 z}},
    Ohangwena/.style   ={insert svg={m 818.82325,632.94327 -0.0538,-3.38631 h 115.24184 v 19.24281 l -59.0722,0.16124 -16.98527,7.41763 -3.87007,-1.61253 -14.56647,-9.56764 -8.60014,1.23626 -7.14887,0.96752 -0.86109,-2.7413 -0.37572,-4.46131 -0.64446,-1.55878 -0.48376,-0.96752 -1.18253,-1.66628 -1.39752,-3.06379 0,0 z}},
    Omaheke/.style     ={insert svg={m 1072.6348,781.08063 0.8062,-0.37625 1.1826,-0.10751 0.1064,33.11163 0.1623,49.1272 -0.5923,1.88127 h -46.9245 l 0.1076,95.03154 -30.04679,-0.10644 -3.22504,-0.43108 -0.21395,-9.03068 -0.21501,-0.53751 -0.43002,-0.37571 -1.12985,-0.26876 -0.69878,0.0543 -0.59117,0.32249 -2.1501,2.68755 -0.215,0.215 -0.21397,0.1075 -4.40753,-0.16233 -0.91376,-0.16178 -0.16124,-0.37573 0.0538,-0.43053 0.21501,-0.42948 v -0.26821 l -0.32359,-0.16179 -2.52521,-0.16018 -0.43108,0.10642 -8.81407,3.49381 -0.64501,0.0543 -3.81631,-0.69822 -0.96858,-0.32413 -0.75144,-0.42893 -2.31129,-2.47254 -0.48376,-0.43108 -0.59126,-0.3225 -0.43109,0.16071 -0.48269,0.37788 -0.7525,0.80626 -0.3225,0.21499 -0.26876,-0.21499 -4.35489,-8.5464 0.0548,-0.64393 2.79504,-7.04298 0.16125,-0.59125 v -0.48376 l -0.48376,-0.48215 -6.61134,-5.48365 -0.32252,-0.53752 0.0538,-0.59178 0.16126,-0.64396 0.3225,-0.5375 0.43108,-0.3768 0.43001,-0.16071 2.68754,-0.16231 0.43001,-0.16181 0.26874,-0.37571 -0.37625,-1.66629 -0.43,-1.18305 -0.21499,-0.37518 -0.26876,-0.16232 -0.43001,-0.10644 -1.02019,-0.16233 -0.53751,-0.10643 -0.43109,-0.16233 -1.02018,-1.28839 -0.75251,-0.43109 -0.21447,-0.43054 -0.21447,-0.48216 -0.0543,-0.53749 0.0543,-0.43109 0.32251,-0.3225 0.21501,-0.16126 2.15002,-0.86055 0.37626,-0.21446 0.16126,-0.26876 0.1075,-0.48375 0.0538,-0.96752 v -0.48321 l -0.10749,-0.32306 h -0.37573 l -3.33201,1.29003 h -0.48375 l -0.32251,-0.32358 -0.1075,-5.42883 -0.10751,-1.45129 -1.34377,-4.03131 -0.26877,-1.02072 -0.59125,-5.3208 -1.29002,-6.61137 -0.16125,-0.32356 -0.215,-0.21393 -0.43001,0.26874 -1.45127,1.18199 -0.0538,0.10697 -0.10749,-0.0538 -1.18251,-0.91376 -0.37572,-0.37625 -0.1618,-0.37573 0.37626,-0.32304 1.55877,-0.86002 0.21392,-0.32357 -0.37572,-0.37572 -0.91322,-0.75197 -0.64501,-0.69876 -1.29002,-2.04308 -0.26874,-0.32303 -0.37572,-0.26876 h -1.88128 l -0.59181,-0.10751 -0.53749,-0.53751 -1.55826,-2.04251 -1.28948,-2.68757 -0.26876,-0.80625 -0.16125,-0.80627 0.5375,-4.51452 0.21394,-0.43055 0.37625,-0.16127 0.43001,-0.0538 0.75253,0.0538 0.43,-0.10748 1.66682,-0.69877 0.48321,-0.37626 0.21501,-0.37572 v -0.85785 l -0.10751,-0.43001 -0.26875,-0.43001 -0.16126,-0.32358 0.16126,-0.43001 1.34377,-1.9888 0.37625,-0.91321 0.37572,-0.32304 0.32304,-0.21447 0.37626,-0.26875 0.26876,-0.48323 -0.10751,-1.1293 -0.16125,-0.43055 -0.16178,-0.26874 -0.21448,-0.10697 -0.215,-0.10696 -0.16125,-0.21501 -0.37626,-0.64501 -0.3225,-0.37572 -0.69876,-0.6993 -0.1618,-0.16124 -0.16178,-0.21447 -0.10697,-0.21447 v -0.43001 l 0.21446,-0.59233 0.75251,-1.34377 1.18199,-1.45074 0.5918,-1.18197 -0.37626,-3.01115 0.5918,-0.53749 2.9563,-1.39754 1.02072,-0.645 1.29002,-1.61253 0.16126,-0.69875 0.0538,-0.64501 -0.43,-2.15005 0.1075,-1.45125 v -0.37573 l -0.0543,-0.43055 -0.1618,-0.5375 v -0.21501 l 0.0548,-0.32357 1.18199,-0.69877 0.16179,-0.43 v -0.48376 l -0.26876,-2.20379 v -0.48376 l 0.10697,-0.48268 0.69929,-0.64501 0.0538,-0.48376 v -0.48376 l -0.37626,-1.61253 -0.16126,-0.37625 -0.16124,-0.10751 -0.80626,0.21502 -1.02126,0.0538 h -0.43002 l -0.26875,-0.16126 -0.0538,-0.37625 0.0538,-2.31128 0.16125,-0.96751 0.43054,-0.43055 0.48323,-0.37573 0.48375,-0.10749 0.43001,-0.10751 0.48322,0.0543 4.94456,1.39807 0.26873,-0.0543 -0.10695,-0.37571 -0.6993,-1.29005 -0.16125,-0.48321 -0.0538,-0.48322 0.0538,-0.53749 0.37625,-0.37628 1.66628,-1.02072 0.59233,-0.43054 0.26875,-0.53751 0.16126,-0.53751 0.1075,-0.9675 v -0.43002 l -0.16179,-0.16125 h -0.37895 l -1.55877,0.26876 -0.43,0.0538 -0.16126,-0.0538 v -0.43001 l 0.21394,-1.55878 0.48375,-1.98878 0.91376,-0.59126 3.43898,-0.75252 0.7525,-0.0538 0.48376,0.37626 0.32251,0.32249 0.3225,0.64501 1.29003,-2.63379 0.3225,-1.07502 1.45127,-7.04137 0.26878,-0.69875 8.43888,-14.24399 1.34376,-1.50502 1.66629,-1.39751 0.48375,-0.26876 22.68287,-8.76139 1.45131,-0.75252 1.50497,-1.45127 0.96754,-0.43001 1.29012,-0.215 2.8488,-0.0538 1.2362,0.16124 38.2707,4.40757 0.8599,0.21501 1.1826,0.645 0.9137,0.26876 2.2038,0.43 h 0.9138 l 1.6662,-0.26876 h 1.9362 l 5.0515,0.69877 2.4188,0.69875 1.7748,0.16126 3.2788,-0.16126 0.6989,-0.10748 2.5262,-0.80627 3.01,-0.16125 0.6999,-0.16341 0,0 z}},
    Oshikoto/.style    ={insert svg={m 934.44028,698.89558 8.76247,0.59124 -0.75251,4.40759 -0.37626,5.32133 -0.48376,0.59125 -1.39753,0.69876 -0.86,0.53751 -1.18253,1.50503 -0.86001,0.48375 -0.75251,0.32251 h -0.69876 l -0.53751,0.0538 -0.32358,0.21501 -0.0538,0.48376 0.37625,3.49381 0.0538,0.69876 -0.1075,0.69875 -0.37518,0.37626 -0.16231,0.59126 -0.0538,0.64502 v 1.88127 l -0.21501,1.45127 -0.21393,0.96752 -0.32358,0.37626 -0.48269,0.215 -0.59233,0.1075 -0.59125,0.16124 -0.48377,0.26877 -0.16124,0.59125 -0.10751,0.59125 -0.16124,0.53752 -1.72004,0.91377 -0.32251,0.64501 -0.21501,0.3225 -0.26874,0.37625 -0.16126,1.12878 v 0.69875 l 0.10751,0.59127 0.43,0.69877 1.66736,2.15002 0.26875,0.64502 -0.32358,0.43 -0.48269,0.43 -2.20485,1.29002 -0.59125,0.26876 h -0.37626 l -0.26876,-0.43001 -0.32305,-0.91375 -0.21446,-0.43001 -0.32305,-0.26876 h -0.5375 l -1.18199,0.26876 -1.50555,0.645 -0.64447,0.21501 -2.95632,-0.16125 -0.21499,-0.10752 -0.21393,-0.16123 -1.72003,-1.50503 -0.75251,-0.43001 -0.86002,-0.37625 -1.12984,0.10749 -0.69876,-0.16124 -0.645,-0.26876 -0.86002,-0.69875 -0.32304,-0.37626 -0.0543,-0.86002 -0.21285,-0.26875 -0.26875,-0.21501 -1.61252,-1.07501 -0.53752,-0.16126 -0.69983,-0.16124 -1.02019,0.215 -0.64503,-0.215 -0.48375,-0.21502 -0.37571,-0.37627 -0.16181,-0.26874 -0.0538,-0.43001 -0.1075,-2.09628 0.0543,-0.37625 0.26876,-0.16126 0.86055,-0.16126 0.32251,-0.16124 0.1075,-0.37625 -0.0538,-0.48376 -0.21501,-1.55878 -0.1075,-0.37626 -0.32251,-0.0538 -0.96751,0.16126 -1.2368,0.3225 -0.21446,0.3225 -0.10751,0.48376 v 0.43001 l -0.1075,0.43001 -0.26875,0.10749 -0.37626,0.0538 -0.43002,-0.0538 -0.37625,-0.10749 -0.0538,-0.37626 0.21501,-1.50502 v -0.43001 l -0.1075,-0.37625 -0.64503,-1.07502 -0.645,-0.43001 -0.75252,-0.37625 -1.61252,0.10749 -0.69983,-0.32249 -0.43001,-0.43002 -0.21392,-0.53749 -0.59234,-0.37626 -0.645,-0.16126 -3.38632,0.86002 -1.98878,3.22504 -4.51507,5.69759 -12.9002,6.77262 -0.37625,0.32249 -0.26877,0.48376 v 0.1075 l -0.53751,-0.48375 -2.8488,-1.55877 -2.95629,-0.80627 -2.84878,-0.0538 -8.76248,-1.29002 -6.3426,-1.98877 -2.68754,-0.26877 -3.33255,-0.91375 -5.6976,-0.86003 0.0538,-1.18252 -0.43001,-1.18251 -0.59126,-3.65506 -0.0548,-1.39753 0.75252,-0.59125 0.96751,-0.48376 0.37626,-1.55878 -1.55878,-1.02125 -0.80626,-1.02127 -0.4816,-1.34378 -0.8611,-1.55878 -1.55769,-3.49381 -0.10751,-1.34376 -0.3225,-0.69876 -0.0548,-3.11754 0.26874,-1.6663 0.64502,-1.61251 1.77377,-2.4188 2.09628,-2.15003 1.45129,-1.88128 1.02018,-0.43001 h 1.02128 l 0.91376,-0.7525 -0.21501,-1.34377 -2.09629,-2.58004 -0.75144,-2.6338 -0.645,-1.18252 -0.37625,-1.29002 0.26874,-3.7088 -0.48267,-2.25755 -0.0548,-2.31129 0.59233,-0.86002 0.80627,-0.53749 2.15003,-3.06381 0.53751,-1.34377 0.37518,-3.01004 -0.26875,-4.08507 -0.26875,-1.07501 -0.64393,-0.75252 -0.64502,-0.1075 v -16.66276 l 14.56648,9.56764 3.87007,1.61253 16.98526,-7.41763 59.07166,-0.16124 0.42947,50.09581 0,0 z}},
    Zambezi/.style     ={insert svg={m 1148.5293,650.59613 39.5086,-8.19271 3.6002,-0.69876 0.8611,-0.0538 35.152,-7.47139 0.8612,-0.0538 0.9127,0.10751 2.4737,0.1075 0.5373,0.3225 0.3758,-0.21499 1.9356,-0.53752 0.86,-0.16124 0.8611,0.16124 1.9877,0.75251 1.3986,0.26877 0.9131,0.48375 1.1821,0.21501 0.3762,0.26876 0.3225,0.37625 0.4311,0.32251 0.7515,0.26875 0.3761,0.0538 h 0.4838 l 0.4827,-0.26875 0.6999,-0.64501 0.5375,-0.32249 0.2688,-0.32252 0.3225,-0.37626 0.4299,-0.16125 h 2.1501 l 4.0313,0.69875 0.215,0.10752 0.2687,0.21501 0.3226,0.26875 0.4837,0.1075 1.505,-0.1075 3.2251,0.69877 1.29,0.59124 0.5913,0.91378 0.9675,-0.43002 0.5924,0.43002 0.5911,0.80626 0.7525,0.59126 h 0.4302 l 0.8599,-0.26876 0.4837,-0.1075 0.1614,0.215 -0.2688,0.86001 v 0.3225 l 0.2688,0.43002 0.2687,0.16125 0.3231,0.1075 h 0.5374 l 0.1619,0.16125 0.8599,0.80627 0.1612,0.1075 0.3764,1.50503 0.1074,0.21499 0.4299,0.1075 0.3226,0.26875 0.215,0.37627 0.1613,0.3225 0.3763,-0.59126 h 0.3762 l 0.6988,0.75251 0.1076,0.32251 -0.055,0.645 0.1072,0.26876 0.1617,0.215 0.5375,0.26876 0.2687,0.215 0.5919,0.86002 0.3762,0.16125 h 0.8063 l 0.6438,0.16125 0.6451,0.43001 0.4838,0.59127 0.3226,0.59125 -3.1176,-0.59125 h -1.8814 l -1.5587,1.61252 -1.5577,0.64501 -1.4512,0.0538 -0.43,-1.02127 -1.3439,0.86 -0.5923,0.0538 -0.3752,-0.59125 -0.7524,0.32251 -0.3763,-0.21501 -0.3225,-0.43 -0.4838,-0.32252 0.2688,-0.75251 -0.4833,0.10751 -0.2144,0.26875 -0.1613,0.32252 -0.3763,0.37625 -0.3231,0.16124 -3.4395,1.18252 -0.9136,0.0538 -0.8601,0.215 -1.0751,0.96752 -0.968,0.21499 -0.323,0.16126 -0.2688,0.75251 -0.3762,0.16125 -0.4826,0.0538 -0.3764,0.16126 -0.3762,0.21499 -0.2139,0.21501 -1.29,1.66627 -1.6126,1.07503 -0.6988,0.64501 -2.4187,2.95629 -0.1612,0.10751 -0.1624,0.32249 -0.6439,0.80629 -0.1624,0.32249 -0.4826,0.10751 -2.15,0.21499 -0.5923,0.16126 -1.6127,-1.55878 -0.1064,-0.75251 -0.2149,-0.3225 -0.3226,-0.16126 -0.3236,-0.3225 -0.8061,-1.61253 -0.5914,-0.59126 -1.0751,-0.16125 -1.6123,-0.10751 -0.6994,0.26876 -0.752,0.80627 -1.3438,2.41877 -0.43,0.37627 -0.431,-0.1075 -0.8063,-0.43001 -0.5375,-0.16125 -0.9674,-0.16125 -0.9676,0.16125 -1.6669,0.86001 -2.2569,2.8488 -1.5588,1.18252 -1.72,0.3225 -0.43,0.21501 -1.3439,1.34376 -0.3761,0.32252 -1.3438,0.59125 -0.5375,0.43001 -0.214,0.26875 -0.215,0.32251 -0.2144,-0.16125 -0.2145,-0.10751 -0.2687,-0.10749 -0.2688,0.0538 -1.6126,1.23627 -0.1612,1.72002 -0.7524,0.75251 -1.3976,0.96753 -0.5925,0.5375 -0.8599,1.34378 -0.5376,0.59127 -0.7525,0.215 -4.4071,4.94507 -0.6992,0.48376 -0.9675,0.16124 -1.1289,1.39754 -0.3235,0.215 -0.214,0.16126 -1.6673,0.59124 h -0.8599 l -0.5919,-0.48376 -0.3756,-2.15002 -0.7526,-2.20378 -0.4301,-0.69877 0.6988,-1.07502 -0.4838,-1.07501 -1.5049,-1.72003 0.3763,-0.80627 -0.2688,-0.48376 -0.4837,-0.37625 -0.2688,-0.59125 -0.1613,-0.59127 -0.4832,-0.215 -0.6445,-0.1075 -0.645,-0.26876 -0.2687,-0.43 -0.6988,-0.86002 -0.6993,-0.59126 -0.4833,0.48376 -0.4299,-0.0538 -0.3764,-0.16124 -0.2685,-0.16126 -0.055,-0.26874 0.055,-0.80628 v -0.3225 l -0.3232,-0.53751 -1.398,-1.72002 -0.5375,-1.29003 -0.5376,-0.75251 -0.1612,-0.26875 -0.053,-0.37625 0.053,-1.18252 -0.1613,-0.16126 -0.3235,-0.0538 -0.3226,-0.10751 -0.1612,-0.37626 v -0.69876 l -0.054,-0.32251 -0.2687,-0.215 -0.6445,-0.3225 -1.7744,-0.10751 -12.9002,1.18251 -20.3613,3.77386 -0.2807,-14.93144 z}},
    Kavango East/.style={insert svg={m 1148.4718,650.72459 -53.6915,10.49163 -0.9139,0.26875 -0.2687,-0.1075 -0.7525,-1.07503 -1.3975,-0.69875 -2.6876,-0.96751 -2.1499,-1.23627 -0.7526,-0.21501 -1.9351,0.1075 -0.6987,-0.1075 -0.861,0.16126 -0.8063,0.37625 -0.8063,0.215 -0.7514,-0.37626 -5.0001,1.39752 -3.7082,1.07502 -0.645,1.34378 -1.5589,0.3225 -1.3975,0.53751 -1.2362,0.1075 -1.0212,-0.96751 -1.3976,-0.75251 -0.8062,-0.21501 -0.3763,0.43001 -0.323,0.215 -0.8064,-0.16126 -0.752,-0.3225 -0.3761,-0.43001 -0.7524,-0.42999 -1.7191,-0.16126 -1.8275,0.1075 -1.1825,0.32251 -0.5913,-0.32251 -1.3987,-1.02126 -1.6124,-0.86002 -0.4827,-0.37625 -0.9138,-1.07503 -1.0749,-0.9675 -1.1826,-0.53752 -1.1825,0.32252 -1.8813,-1.61252 -0.5376,-0.21502 -1.5577,0.3225 h -0.6449 l -0.5374,-0.3225 -1.6127,1.45127 -1.1287,-0.48375 -1.2901,-0.10751 -1.075,0.32251 -0.6988,0.64502 -0.3762,-0.37627 -0.645,0.26876 -0.645,0.10751 h -1.2889 l -2.7424,0.26874 -0.4299,-0.0538 -1.6665,-0.59127 -1.7736,-1.07502 h -7.4715 l -0.3224,0.21502 -0.5375,0.96751 -0.2151,0.26876 -0.7525,-0.0538 -1.0749,-0.37626 -1.0203,-0.48375 -0.4305,-0.37626 -0.4306,-0.91377 -0.9675,-0.215 -0.9407,0.094 c 0.3822,1.36474 0.8816,3.02187 1.1134,3.25408 0.403,0.40313 0,2.01566 0,2.01566 l -9.5409,8.46576 11.1532,22.17222 c 0,0 -1.075,2.82194 -1.2093,3.35945 -0.1345,0.5375 -0.1345,3.49379 -0.1345,4.16569 0,0.67188 0.4032,4.56881 0.4032,5.2407 0,0.67188 -0.1344,3.76256 -0.2687,4.56882 -0.1345,0.80627 0.1343,2.68755 0.403,3.76256 0.2688,1.07501 -0.6717,2.41879 -1.3436,3.49381 -0.672,1.07501 -2.4189,1.74688 -3.6283,1.74688 -1.2093,0 -2.6875,2.01568 -3.0906,2.68757 -0.2404,0.40098 -1.0046,2.14412 -1.583,3.48789 l 70.2094,-0.73532 -0.053,-8.76138 v -34.72298 l 0.9137,-0.0538 22.7367,-0.96752 50.751,-10.47012 -0.3377,-14.80298 z}},
    Kavango West/.style={insert svg={m 1008.925,715.06274 c 1.2094,0 2.9562,-0.67187 3.6281,-1.74688 0.672,-1.07502 1.6126,-2.4188 1.3438,-3.49381 -0.2687,-1.07502 -0.5375,-2.9563 -0.403,-3.76256 0.1343,-0.80626 0.2687,-3.89695 0.2687,-4.56882 0,-0.67189 -0.4032,-4.56883 -0.4032,-5.24071 0,-0.6719 0,-3.62819 0.1345,-4.1657 0.1343,-0.5375 1.2093,-3.35944 1.2093,-3.35944 l -11.1534,-22.17221 9.5408,-8.46576 c 0,0 0.4033,-1.61253 0,-2.01566 -0.2321,-0.23221 -0.7309,-1.88934 -1.1131,-3.25408 l -0.1344,0.0134 -2.6876,0.59126 -8.0625,0.1075 -7.52518,-2.31128 -0.75201,-0.48376 -2.09571,0.16126 -1.39808,-0.32253 h -0.53742 l -1.02077,0.21501 -1.61254,0.64502 -3.97756,0.21501 -6.18134,-1.18252 -4.19258,-2.15006 -1.82699,-0.48375 -0.69929,-0.5375 -0.91323,-1.29003 -2.74183,-2.95629 -0.43001,-0.32251 -0.86056,-0.48376 -0.48321,-0.43 -0.21501,-0.48376 -0.26875,-0.91376 -0.16125,-0.37625 -2.4188,-2.09628 -0.64501,-0.32252 -0.16125,-0.59125 -1.61253,-3.27881 -1.12876,-0.32252 -0.16179,-0.10748 -0.0543,-0.53752 -0.80626,-1.93502 -0.26876,-0.26876 -0.3225,-0.16126 -0.16125,-0.48374 -0.0548,-0.32252 -0.37626,-0.0538 h -21.01659 v 19.24279 l 0.43001,50.09582 8.76138,0.59125 49.12823,2.79505 -0.0537,19.08155 11.97346,-0.12522 c 0.5785,-1.3438 1.3427,-3.08692 1.5831,-3.4879 0.4042,-0.67135 1.8823,-2.68703 3.0917,-2.68703 z}},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  cm={0.53750861,0,0,-0.53750861,(0,0)},
  thick, line cap=round, line join=round,
  Namibia={every region/.style=draw}]
\foreach \region[count=\i, evaluate={\col=(\i-1)/.13}] in {
  Kunene, Omusati, Oshana, Ohangwena, Oshikoto, Kavango East, Zambezi,
  Erongo, Otjozondjupa, Omaheke, Khomas, Hardap, Karas, Kavango West}
  \path[Namibia/every region/.try, Namibia/\region/.try];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The SVG file offers much too many coordinates for the scale of a PDF page. It would be wise to find a different source or filter the one you have. Anyway, [here's the full file](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tex.sx/blob/master/656268.tex).

Comment: Can you add [Sossuvlei dunes](https://images.app.goo.gl/Y3tAweDjMqob8FfK8) texture? Just kidding right...

Comment: great, thanks a lot @Qrrbrbirlbel ! this was super helpful.