# Typesetting Sorting Diagrams

Tags: diagrams

I am typesetting some diagrams representing sorting algorithms similar to those found in [Miller and Ranum Python Book](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/SortSearch/sorting.html) partly as an exercise in learning TikZ. I'm trying to typeset something similar to the Merge sort diagrams:

Splitting phase:

[image: Splitting phase diagram]

Merging phase

[image: Merging phase diagram]

I started with a multipart rectangle but the drop shadow overwrites the filled nodes (unless white) — on the second row I experimented with individual nodes but this leads to problems with fonts (such as Lucida) where not all digits have the dame height.

Here's my code for these parts:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength{\OUmatrixSepWidth}
\newcommand{\OUsetMatrixSepWidth}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\OUmatrixSepWidth}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\Large  

  \OUsetMatrixSepWidth{3em}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [myInnerBlock/.style={rectangle,draw,align=center}
    ,myInnerBlockL/.style={rectangle,draw,align=center,fill=red!20}
    ,myInnerBlockR/.style={rectangle,draw,align=center,fill=blue!20}
    ,myRectangleSplit/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,draw,rectangle split part align={center,base}} % requires library shapes.multipart
    ,line/.style={draw,thick,red,-triangle 60}
    ]
    \matrix[column sep=0.3\OUmatrixSepWidth, row sep=0.5\OUmatrixSepWidth]
    {
      % row 1
      \node[myRectangleSplit,rectangle split allocate boxes=10,rectangle split parts=10,drop shadow,rectangle split part fill={red!20,red!20,red!20,red!20,red!20,blue!20}] (unsorted) 
      { 3\nodepart{two}0\nodepart{three}1\nodepart{four}8\nodepart{five}7\nodepart{six}2\nodepart{seven}5\nodepart{eight}4\nodepart{nine}9\nodepart{ten}6}; \\
      % row 2
      \node (r2ac) {}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,left=0.3\OUmatrixSepWidth of r2ac] (r2a5) {7}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,left=0pt of r2a5] (r2a4) {8}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,left=0pt of r2a4] (r2a3) {1}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,left=0pt of r2a3] (r2a2) {0}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,left=0pt of r2a2] (r2a1) {3}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,right=0.3\OUmatrixSepWidth of r2ac] (r2a6) {2}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,right=0pt of r2a6] (r2a7) {5}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,right=0pt of r2a7] (r2a8) {4}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,right=0pt of r2a8] (r2a9) {9}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,right=0pt of r2a9] (r2a10) {6}; 
      \\
      % row 3
      % row 4
      % row 5
    }; 
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Which looks like:

[image: Query Image Output]

The multipart rectangle would appear nicer but how do you get the drop shadow to not overwrite the rectangle? Is there a better way that I'm missing ? Would a tree structure be easier ? Not to mention getting the lines with right angles.

Comment: You can use layers for that and put it in the background layer.

Comment: See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43618/drawing-a-proper-shadow-for-overlapping-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code and the answer from here: [Drawing a proper shadow for overlapping objects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43618/drawing-a-proper-shadow-for-overlapping-objects), and adjusting the `shadow yshift` key, you can have shadows properly drawn. For extra info about shadows see page 415 on PGF manual.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength{\OUmatrixSepWidth}
\newcommand{\OUsetMatrixSepWidth}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\OUmatrixSepWidth}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  /tikz/node on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@node@finish\expandafter{\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\endpgfonlayer\tikz@node@finish}%
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Large  

  \OUsetMatrixSepWidth{3em}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [myInnerBlock/.style={rectangle,draw,align=center}
    ,myInnerBlockL/.style={rectangle,draw,align=center,fill=red!20}
    ,myInnerBlockR/.style={rectangle,draw,align=center,fill=blue!20}
    ,myRectangleSplit/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,draw,rectangle split part align={center,base}} % requires library shapes.multipart
    ,line/.style={draw,thick,red,-triangle 60}
    ]
    \matrix[column sep=0.3\OUmatrixSepWidth, row sep=0.5\OUmatrixSepWidth]
    {
      % row 1
      \node[myRectangleSplit,rectangle split allocate boxes=10,rectangle split parts=10,drop shadow={on layer=back,shadow yshift
=3ex},rectangle split part fill={red!20,red!20,red!20,red!20,red!20,blue!20}] (unsorted) 
      { 3\nodepart{two}0\nodepart{three}1\nodepart{four}8\nodepart{five}7\nodepart{six}2\nodepart{seven}5\nodepart{eight}4\nodepart{nine}9\nodepart{ten}6}; \\[2ex]
      % row 2
      \node (r2ac) {}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,left=0.3\OUmatrixSepWidth of r2ac] (r2a5) {7}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,left=0pt of r2a5] (r2a4) {8}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,left=0pt of r2a4] (r2a3) {1}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,left=0pt of r2a3] (r2a2) {0}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,left=0pt of r2a2] (r2a1) {3}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,right=0.3\OUmatrixSepWidth of r2ac] (r2a6) {2}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockL,right=0pt of r2a6] (r2a7) {5}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,right=0pt of r2a7] (r2a8) {4}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,right=0pt of r2a8] (r2a9) {9}; 
      \node[myInnerBlockR,right=0pt of r2a9] (r2a10) {6}; 
      \\
      % row 3
      % row 4
      % row 5
    }; 
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this — very helpful. A couple of questions: (1) The row separation looks bigger in your case by quite some way (even though the row sep keys are the same; (2) The code for the pgfkeys is TeX — could it be written in LaTeX ? (3) The shadow yshift=3ex appears by magic — what is the base of the shift ?

Comment: @PhilMolyneux In order to answer your questions: (1) and (3) If you look at the code you can see `\\[2ex]` in the of the splitted node; this means `insert a new line with vertical space of 2ex`. Next, I did some trials and verified that the `shadow yshift` need some adjustment, and one that looked better for me is `3ex`; this means `move shadow up by 3ex`. As such, in the end the shadow only moved up `1ex (3ex-2ex)`. Four LaTeX units you can see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm.

Comment: @PhilMolyneux  For question (2) PGF/TikZ is attached to `TeX` and, as such, can be used both in plain `TeX`, `LaTeX` or `ConTeXt`. Also `LaTeX` add some `macros` to `TeX` to make it more consistent and robust. But on this case I don't see a reason to change.