# Drawing divided table

Tags: tables

Can anyone recommend any tutorial/library or just explain how can I draw this type of table, divided into few part with arrows? Like on [this picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg/300px-Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg.png):

[image]

Comment: I would be inclined to do this with the TiKZ package, using its `matrix` library, in conjunction with the `shapes.multipart` library.

Comment: The title should be "Representing a sorting algorithm for lists". No ?

Comment: @projetmbc Good call.  That yields a related question: [Typesetting Sorting Diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118492)

Comment: @Alan Munn thank you for your help, I will try it

Comment: @projetmbc Thanks for your suggestion, I will remember

Comment: @ziva The question I linked to has an example very much like yours, so if you play around with that and then run into problems you can edit your question to get more specific help.

Comment: @AlanMunn The question does, but _the answer does not_. Therefore I'm quite against calling it a duplicate (since duplicates have to be answered, which is essentially not the case here).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses the following packages:

- [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) (also [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox))

  `forest` is used to create the upper part of the tree, every node of this tree will use the algorithm behind the `sort` key. Every `m`irrored node will be placed at the orthogonal opposite of the last line. The edges of the lower part are rudimentary drawn with an `edge` path operator of TikZ (`forest` offers a few options for edges that are not used here).
- [`expl3`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3)

  The `expl3` package provides a sorting algorithm for lists.
- [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring)

  The `xstring` package provides a `\StrSubstitute` macro that first replaces all spaces   to commas `,` for the sorting macro. The sorted result is then again thrown into `\StrSubstitute`  to re-replace the commas to spaces.

Furthermore, the `calc` library from TikZ is used to place the sorted nodes at the other side (this could have been easily done without `calc`) as well as the PGFmath function `strrepeat`.

A similar approach for a `calc`-less positioning can be found in [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120605/16595) (look for `Stern Brocot at` and `Stern Brocot at*`). This is also the answer where I first used the `strrepeat` function.

This function is only used once to automatically create the name of the first child of the last level of the tree (here: `39`) so that it can be used later as `\forestOnes`.
The `sort level` key also sets up the `\forestSortLevel` macro so that it can be used inside the `sort` key.

#### Possible improvements

- Getting the  maximum level directly from `forest` and not from the user.
- Sorting with spaces without the need to replace the spaces (or maybe a LaTeX3 solution for the replacing).
- Automatic splitting of a list of numbers by `forest` so that one does only need to add the root node.
- Exploiting something like `execute at end picture` but for `forest` for the lower part of the tree. The `sort` key is actually executed before anything is drawn (and outside of TikZ) which is the reason that all `\node`s (and their edges) are saved in `\forestSortedNodes`. The same is true for the `\coordinate` call which just as well should be setup by `sort level`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,expl3,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{strrepeat}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathint@{#2}%
    \pgfmath@count\pgfmathresult
    \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
    \pgfutil@loop
      \ifnum\pgfmath@count>0\relax
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter{\pgfmathresult#1}%
      \advance\pgfmath@count-1\relax
    \pgfutil@repeat
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*\sortList[1]{
  \clist_sort:Nn #1 {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}
      \sort_return_swapped:
      \sort_return_same:
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\forestset{
  sort/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{level()>\forestSortLevel}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
      % sort content of node
      \StrSubstitute{\forestov{content}}{ }{,}[\myList]%
      \sortList\myList
      \StrSubstitute{\myList}{,}{ }[\myList]%
      % add corresponding node on the other side of the tree
      \pgfmathparse{strrepeat("1",level())}%
      \xappto\forestSortedNodes{%
        \noexpand\node at ($(\forestov{name}|-m)!-1!(\forestov{name})$)
        (m\forestov{name}) {\myList}}%
      % add edges
      % edges to original forest tree
      \pgfmathparse{level()==\forestSortLevel}%
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        % \forestFirst=\forestLast? only on parent (the 10 in this example)
        \forestOget{\forestov{@first}}{name}\forestFirst
        \forestOget{\forestov{@last}}{name}\forestLast
        \xappto\forestSortedNodes{{%
          [<-] edge (\forestOv{\forestov{@first}}{name})
            \ifx\forestFirst\forestLast\else edge
            (\forestOv{\forestov{@last}}{name})\fi
          }}%
      \fi
      % eges to original forest tree
      \ifnum\forestov{@parent}=0\else
        \xappto\forestSortedNodes{edge (m\forestOv{\forestov{@parent}}{name})}%
      \fi
      \gappto\forestSortedNodes{;}%
    \fi}}
\forestset{
  sort level/.code=%
    \def\forestSortedNodes{}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\forestSortLevel{#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\forestOnes{strrepeat("1",\forestSortLevel+1)}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
  /tikz/arrows=->, /tikz/>=Latex, %/tikz/nodes={draw},
  for tree={delay={sort}}, sort level=2
[38 27 43 3 9 82 10
  [38 27 43 3
    [38 27 [39][27]]
    [43 3 [43][3]]
  ]
  [9 82 10
    [9 82 [9] [82]]
    [10 [10]]
  ]
]
%
\coordinate (m) at (!|-!\forestOnes);
\forestSortedNodes
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: `\sort_ordered:` and `\sort_reversed:` are deprecated as of 2018-12-31; the right functions are `\sort_return_same:` and `\sort_return_swapped:`

Comment: @egreg Even worse: `l3sort` disappeared.