# Draw a match using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a macro which draw a enlighten match using TikZ in my document. I'm successful :

```
\newcommand\allumette[2]{
    \fill [PeachPuff] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+4,#2+0.2);
    \fill [PeachPuff!60!Black] (#1,#2) -- ++(4,0)-- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \draw (#1,#2) -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \shade[ball color=red] (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    \draw (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
}
```

Output :

[image: output]

However, I'm not successful while trying to draw the flame over the tip.

**Edit :** Here is a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand\allumette[2]{
    \fill [PeachPuff] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+4,#2+0.2);
    \fill [PeachPuff!60!Black] (#1,#2) -- ++(4,0)-- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \draw (#1,#2) -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \shade[ball color=red] (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    \draw (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\allumette{0}{0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you include a Minimum Working Example? That should include the `\documentclass` command and `\begin{document}` `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome! It would be good if you would complete your code. Have to looked at `tikzsymbols`? I think it includes a flame or something similar.

Comment: Some other examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121822/best-way-to-draw-matchstick-pictures/164580#164580

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw a generic flame. I stole it from [How to create Candle Symbol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43739/how-to-create-candle-symbol-in-latex). I used yellow in the absence of the definition of the colors.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\allumette[2]{
    \fill [yellow] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+4,#2+0.2);
    \fill [yellow!60!black] (#1,#2) -- ++(4,0)-- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \draw (#1,#2) -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \shade[ball color=red] (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    \draw (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
}
\allumette{0.1}{0.2}
\filldraw[orange,scale=0.5,shift={(8.2,1.2)}]  (0,0) .. controls (-1.5,1.25) and (.5,2) .. (-.2,4) .. controls (1,2.5) and (1,.5) .. (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But depends on how much you want to procrastinate. Instead of a new command you can define a `/.pic` for this and turn the flame on and off or refer to nodes in it etc.

Comment: It looks like I want, but I'm using a macro because I need to integrate it in more complexe figures. I would like to have a macro for the match only, and one for the match and the flame, but I do not understand the placement of the flame in the command you've given.

Comment: Edit : I finally understood, I modified your command to adapt to the given coordinates.