# TiKz - Draw a recursive plot with matches

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I would like to produce the following draws and more. Can someone gives me some clues to achieve this easily ?

I have found the following post to draw one single match :
[Draw a match using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344598/draw-a-match-using-tikz)

Forgive me to not give a MWE.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conceptually similar to Vinzza's answer but with `pic`s instead of macros and the possibility to draw a single tower with `matches`. A single `match` is obtained as `pic=match`.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/match/.style={code={%
    \fill [PeachPuff] (0,0) rectangle (0+4,0+0.2);
    \fill [PeachPuff!60!Black] (0,0) -- ++(4,0)-- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \shade[ball color=red] (0+4,0+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    \draw (0+4,0+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
}},pics/matches/.style={code={
    \foreach \YY in {0,...,#1}
    {\path foreach \XX in {0,...,\YY}
    { (-2.2-4.4*\XX,-2.2+4.8*#1-4.8*\YY)pic[rotate=90]{match} (-2.2-4.4*\XX,2.2+4.8*#1-4.8*\YY)pic{match}
    (-2.2+4.4*\XX,-2.2+4.8*#1-4.8*\YY)pic[rotate=90]{match} (-2.2+4.4*\XX,2.2+4.8*#1-4.8*\YY)pic{match}}
    (2.2+4.4*\YY,-2.2+4.8*#1-4.8*\YY)pic[rotate=90]{match};}
}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25,transform shape]
\path foreach \Z in {0,...,5} 
{({9*\Z*(\Z+1)/2+2*\Z},0) pic{matches=\Z}
node[below=3cm,scale=6]{$\the\numexpr\Z+1$ stories}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiice!! I always forget I can use pics... And I'll try to remember the `\the\numexpr\Z+1` which is probably way better than `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`! :D

Comment: Thanks for your code. Does `pics` is a TiKz mechanism to define "graphical" ?

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, it is a Ti*k*Zy means of defining little pictures that you may want to repeat. They are explained in detail in section **18 Pics: Small Pictures on Paths** of pgfmanual v 3.1.4.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to keep it my mind.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with several \foreach, it may not be the prettiest way to do it, but I find it quite simple to do!

Note that I added a scope to shift/scale/rotate in the `\allumette` command (in the link you gave)!

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\allumette[3]{
  \begin{scope}[line width=.2,shift={(#1,#2)},rotate=#3,scale=.2,shift={(.25,0)}]
    \fill [PeachPuff] (0,0) rectangle (0+4,0+.2);
    \fill [PeachPuff!60!Black] (0,0) -- ++(4,0)-- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,.2) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \shade[ball color=red] (0+4,0+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    \draw (0+4,0+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  %% Set the position of the next tower
  \coordinate (dum) at (0,0);

  \foreach \t in {0,...,5}{  
    \begin{scope}[shift={(dum)}]

      %%%%%%%%%% Draw to tower of height \t+1 %%%%%
      \foreach \z in {0,...,\t}{
        \foreach \x in {-\z,...,\z}{
          \allumette{\t+\x}{\t+1-\z}{0} % Horizontal
          \allumette{\t+\x}{\t-\z}{90}  % Vertical
        }
        \allumette{\t+\z+1}{\t-\z}{90} % Last one on the line
      }
      %%%%%%%%%% Draw to tower of height \t+1 %%%%%

      %% The text under the tower
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\foo{\t+1}
      \node[anchor=north] at (\t+.5,-.5) {\bfseries\foo{} \'etages};

      %% Set the position of the next tower
      \coordinate (dum) at (2*\t+2,0);
    \end{scope}
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives
[image: Results, Tower of matches]

Comment: Thanks. I vote for the other code because you say yourself that is great. ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc This answer is certainly no "worse" than the other one. Some users prefer macros, others pics. There are some arguments in favor of pics like the ability to use the `pic actions` and other pgf keys more easily but in this application non of that gets used at this point.

Comment: To be honest, if I could I would vote for the both answers. I let you decide if you want that I vote for the other code. :-)

Comment: @projetmbc It's fine like that, don't worry! :)