# How to draw 2 or 3 piles of matches (or bean seeds)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I learned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344598/draw-a-match-using-tikz) from enzo83130 and percusse to draw a match stick, but I do not know how to draw a pile yet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\allumette[2]{
    \fill [yellow] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+4,#2+0.2);
    \fill [yellow!60!black] (#1,#2) -- ++(4,0)-- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \draw (#1,#2) -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \shade[ball color=red] (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    \draw (#1+4,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
}
\allumette{0.1}{0.2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is `here`? Code should be attributed and should include a link to the original.

Comment: Sorry. It was bad.

Comment: The link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344598/draw-a-match-using-tikz?rq=1

Comment: What does this have to do with bean seeds? What have you tried? You can just put more matches wherever you wish by repeating the command with new coordinates.

Comment: How do you want the pile of matches look like?

Comment: I have no preference. I want the stack just to illustrate a problem about games, where each player remove one or more sticks.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163828/15874 can help you with a PSTricks solution.

Comment: @gernot For what it is worth, I don't find this question to be a duplicate of the one cited.  That one is about "drawing" whereas this one is, to my view, all about "stacking".  Drawing, while more comprehensive in its scope, carries a lot of extra code baggage that I don't think is needed for the current application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I save the unit match as `\match` and then use various stacking commands from `stackengine` and/or `tabstackengine` packages.  It can be customized for horizontal and vertical stacking gaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,tabstackengine}
\savestack\match{\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [yellow] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.2);
    \fill [yellow!60!black] (0,0) -- ++(4,0)-- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(0.1,-0.05) -- ++(-4,0) -- ++(-0.1,0.05);
    \shade[ball color=red] (4,0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    \draw (4,0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\setstacktabbedgap{2pt}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\tabbedShortstack{%
\match&&\\
\match&&\match\\
\match&\match&\match\\
\match&\match&\match
}

\bigskip
\setstackgap{S}{-1pt}
\Shortstack{\match\\\match\match\\\match\match\match}

\bigskip
\Shortstack[r]{\match\\\match\match\\\match\match\match}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For fun, here is the [coffee] bean version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,tabstackengine}

\savestack\bean{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\color{white}\rotatebox[origin=center]{45}{%
  \sffamily\scalebox{.4}[1.2]{S}}}{%
  \color{brown!70!black}\scalebox{2}[1.5]{$\bullet$}}}\begin{document}  
\setstacktabbedgap{-2pt}
\setstackgap{S}{-2pt}
\tabbedShortstack{%
\bean&&\\
\bean&&\bean\\
\bean&\bean&\bean\\
\bean&\bean&\bean
}

\bigskip
\setstackgap{S}{-3.5pt}
\Shortstack{\bean\\\bean\bean\\\bean\bean\bean}

\bigskip
\setstackgap{S}{-1pt}
\Shortstack[r]{\bean\\\bean\bean\\\bean\bean\bean}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely the `\allumette` macro is pointless here?

Comment: @cfr Yes and no.  I have edited to make it more sensical.  It is, on one hand, pointless since actual coordinates can be substituted, but it is useful, on the other hand, since coordinates are specified relative to starting point.

Comment: Steve B. Segletes, It was very good. Now I have the possibility of making the cells with varying numbers of toothpicks. Thank you.

Comment: @benedito I am glad to have been of assistance.

Comment: But it would be just the same if you used `(0,0)` and relative coordinates because you're only putting one match stick in each `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @cfr Good point.  Fixed.