# tikz: Saving repeatedly drawn parts of pictures to increase compilation speed

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

I'm drawing a number of very similar images using tikz, like this:

[image]

Code (and motivation) are given at [Making cards for Magic: The Gathering and similar card games](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184964/making-cards-for-magic-the-gathering-and-similar-card-games).

Compilation is slow. I've timed it, and most of the time is being spent repeatedly drawing the same image, in this case

[image]

It seems to me that there should be some way to save this material once it is rendered, to prevent the duplication of work. [Is it possible to reuse a part of a tikz image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/is-it-possible-to-reuse-a-part-of-a-tikz-image?lq=1) points me in a sensible direction, in that it suggests using a box. My problem is that I have no idea how to get the text to be placed sensibly relative to the material saved in a box... .

Comment: You can look in to the `pic` facility of `tikz`, I hope.

Comment: Thanks!  In case anyone else is reading this: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tree-pic/

Comment: @Harish Kumar: From the 3.0.0 manual, it seems as if the material is redrawn every time. Are you sure pic is faster?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/837/pdf-letterhead-as-document-background It might be possible to reuse the image as a background image as suggested here?

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that saveboxes are faster than macros.  It should be remembered that the savebox is larger than the text area inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%create border around empty text area 4cm by 2cm

\newsavebox{\myborder}
\savebox{\myborder}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=red, thick] {\parbox[t][2cm]{4cm}{\strut}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

% align edges

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node[inner sep=0] (border) {\usebox{\myborder}}
  (border.north west) node[below right] {\begin{minipage}{4cm}
  With any luck this text will fit nicely into the borders drawn previously.
  \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}

% align centers

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node[inner sep=0] {\usebox{\myborder}}
  (0,0) node {\parbox[t][2cm]{4cm}
  {With any luck this text will fit nicely into the borders drawn previously.}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned border]

Comment: "savebox is larger than the text area inside": due to `outer sep`?

Comment: Actually, the inner sep and line thickness.  But it is worse than that.  Further tests with registration marks showed that even when both nodes are centered, the second node is 1.5pt left of the first.

Comment: Aha!  I needed a % after { to prevent adding an extra space.