# Combine multiple tikz-cd diagrams as in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Is there a neat way to combine multiple tikz-cd diagrams into one figure such that I can arrange them as I want (e.g., based on screen coordinates) and they all have the same font size, I can add labels, etc?
I want to arrange `tikz-cd` diagrams of different sizes in one figure and be able to freely add labels, etc. to them. Optimally with a `tikzfigure` environment but all I found was that tikz environments are not to be nested.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, please provide at least a sketch, what you like to have. Also some `tikz-cd` diagrams will be of help. BTW, you can include your `tikz-cd` diagram as subfigures using `subcaption` package. In this case you can add sub-captions.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this. I previously tried combining the PDFs of all individual `tikz-cd` diagrams with subfigures but this resulted in mismatched font sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the desired solution here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525046/225692

As was pointed out in the comments, one can also combine `tikz-cd` diagrams as subfigures with the `subcaption` package.